# What are the differences between these two ways of doing TypeScript methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What are the differences between the way greetOne is made and the way greetTwo is?

When should you use the style of one over the other?

What are the pros and cons of each style?

TypeScript:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greetOne() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
    greetTwo =()=> {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        var _this = this;
        this.greetTwo = function () {
            return "Hello, " + _this.greeting;
        };
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greetOne = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
```

Comment: They are sort of roughly equivalent, but why would you want to write two when you could just write one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`greetOne` is a method while `greetTwo` is a property which value happens to be an arrow function.

The biggest difference is that you can override methods in a subclass but you cannot override properties (by inheritance), they are re-assigned in the sub-class instance.

Consider the following example

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
        console.log("One: "+ this.greetOne())
        console.log("Two: "+ this.greetTwo())
     }
     greetOne() {
         return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
     }
     greetTwo =()=> {
         return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
     }
}

class GreeterChild extends Greeter {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
    }
    greetOne() {
        return "Child Hello, " + this.greeting;   //<== OK
    }        
    greetTwo = ()=> {
        return "Child Hello, " + this.greeting;  //<= will not work as you expect
    }
}

new GreeterChild("Joe")
```

The console result will be

```
One: Child Hello, Joe
Two: Hello, Joe
```

View this example on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%09%09console.log(%22One%3A%20%22%2B%20this.greetOne())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%09%09console.log(%22Two%3A%20%22%20%2B%20this.greetTwo())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greetOne()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greetTwo%20%3D()%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09class%20GreeterChild%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(message)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greetOne()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Child%20Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%3C%3D%3D%20OK%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greetTwo%20%3D%20()%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Child%20Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%20%20%2F%2F%3C%3D%20will%20not%20work%20as%20expected%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09new%20GreeterChild(%22Joe%22)) to see what happens: `this.greetTwo` is **re**-assigned inside `GreeterChild` constructor **after** the super call to the constructor or `Greeter` which logs the value returned by the arrow function, as defined in `Greeter`.

*javascript snip*

```
function GreeterChild(message) {
    var _this = this;
    _super.call(this, message);
    this.greetTwo = function () {
        return "Child Hello, " + _this.greeting; //<= will not work as expected
    };
}
```

In short, use `methods`, not `arrow functions` (properties) if you need to subclass and override.

Arrow functions have their own advantages, such as preserving the surrounding `this` of the class instance, which can come handy if you call them from a DOM element event handler for instance.

Answer (score 0):

greetOne is from the compilere and IDE known as method. greetTwo as a property.

[image: greetOne]
[image: greetTwo]

So a "normal" typescript user will define methods like greetOne because it is from others known as method.

By greetTwo you actually create a property from a function type and set it with a lamba expression.

```
greetTwo: () => string = () => {/*...*/};
```

For one thing this is usefull. If you want to give your method to another function as callback.

```
// this will not work as expected because jQuery overwrite the "this"
$(".myclass").click(g.greetOne);

// this will work as expected because typescript compiler replace "this" in lambas with "_this"
$(".myclass").click(g.greetTwo);

// but I dont like that I prevere this style, because I think it is more readable and clear
$(".myclass").click(() => { g.greetOne() }); 
// or
$(".myclass").click(function() { g.greetOne() });
```

Hier the JavaScript from your Greeter in EcmaScript 5.

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        var _this = this;
        this.greetTwo = function () {
            return "Hello, " + _this.greeting;
        };
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greetOne = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
var g = new Greeter("");
```